# WebClient: How to set the host name (host header)?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

How can I set a `Host` header value with `WebClient` that is different than the one I use in the URL? For example, in

```
webClient.OpenRead("http://192.168.10.10/");
```

the host header value would be "192.168.10.10" but I want it to be something different (e.g. "example.org").

Comment: I generalized your question so that future visitors will find it more useful.

Answer (score -3):

The address must have URL format

```
webClient.OpenRead("http://192.168.10.10");
```

Comment: That's not what he was asking.